# Gaussian filter looks pixelated

Tags: matlab, filters, gaussian

What does it mean when an image looks pixelated after a Gaussian filter (Multivariate Gaussian Distribution filter) is applied (in context of mu, Sigma, and the meshgrid created), and what parameters can one alter to minimize this effect and make the image look smoother?

**Sample code (MATLAB):**

```
d1 = 20
d2 = 20
d3 = 20
mu = [0 0 0]; 
Sigma = 30*[1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1];
[X1,X2,X3] = meshgrid(linspace(-10,10,d1)', linspace(-10,10,d2)', linspace(-10,10,d3)');
X4 = [X1(:) X2(:) X3(:)];
p = mvnpdf(X4, mu, Sigma);
F = reshape(p,d1,d2,d3);
```

I am convolving the filter above with a 3-D matrix, a roughly 90*60*100 matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pixelation often occurs when an image's dimensions are distorted. If the image looks pixelated, it is probably not so much a problem with the Gaussian as it is with the way the image is sized or resized.

Answer (score 1):

An image shouldn't look pixelated after filtered by a Gaussian (lowpass) kernel... instead look at the following figure:

[image]